# Open a cross domain file - .htaccess limitation or fs limitation? node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, .htaccess, plesk

#### I'm stumped.

So I'm attempting to read a file cross-domain through fs. lib. It's responding that it does not exist. I've attempted to open the file with my browser and it works just fine. Should I be using something different than fs?

I've tried adding a port `http://www.mydomain.com:80/uploads/docs/doc.doc` but that does not work either.

Running a vhost on plesk panel. (apache)

Comment: You need to show the code that fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Should I be using something different than fs?*

Yes. The [`fs` module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) is meant for interacting with the machine's local file systems, rather than handling [network communication](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) such as HTTP requests and responses.

You can use the [`http` module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html), specifically [`http.get()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback), to request a file from an HTTP server:

```
http.get('http://www.mydomain.com/uploads/docs/doc.doc', function (res) {
    // process the response, `res`, as desired

    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
        // Example, piping the response to a file on disk:

        res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/doc.doc'));
    } else {
        console.error('The address is unavailable. (%d)', res.statusCode);
    }
});
```

`res` will be an [`http.IncomingMessage`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage), which are [`stream.Readable`s](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable).

Comment: I knew it would be an fs issue. Thanks.